# Segmentation Fault when returning from a function call in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This program is being written in C and is compiled with GCC by a server in a PuTTy session. The program is also being run by that same server.

I'm sending a function call with 2 parameters. "a", a two dimensional integer array with 11 columns and a varying amount of rows and "clients", an integer which designates how many rows exist in the array. (The server asks the user how many clients will be serviced and creates "a" as an array with that many rows. These function calls are ideally supposed to work for any number of clients.)

In this function call, the column that holds the current state is examined for each client. If any client is in the state (represented by integers) 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4, then the function returns a 1. Else, the function returns a 0. This function is depicted below.

```
int incomplete(int a[][11], int clients) {
    for (i = 0; i < clients; i++) {
        if (a[i][1] == 0 || a[i][1] == 1 || a[i][1] == 2 || a[i][1] == 3 || a[i][1] == 4) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The function making the call is the condition for a while loop to continue looping. If any client is found to be in state 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4, the while loop should continue executing.

```
while (incomplete(a, clients) == 1) {
    ...
}
```

However, upon returning a value, the program immediately crashes with a "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" error. Now I have done research, and segmentation faults often happen due to leaking memory, accessing memory locations that are out of bounds, stack problems, etc.

The problem is, I don't see how I'm getting a segmentation fault when the function call is so cut and dry. Send in an array with 33 integers (nothing huge, just 3 clients by 11 columns of info), a single integer denoting the number of rows, then return a single integer for comparison.

Funnily enough, a similar function with similar parameters functions just perfectly fine. It just has no return value.

```
void printArray(int a[][11], int clients) {
    printf("\n\n+-------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+");
    for (i = 0; i < clients; i++) {
        printf("\n| %5d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d |",
            a[i][0], a[i][1], a[i][2], a[i][3],
            a[i][4], a[i][5], a[i][6], a[i][7],
            a[i][8], a[i][9], a[i][10]);
    }
    printf("\n+-------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+\n\n");
}
```

Which is called by the method...

```
printArray(a, clients);
```

I can reproduce the problem by just returning any integer value in the incomplete() function. I can also say that processing is completed for the incomplete() function by placing dummy printf statements to trace execution of the code before it predictably crashes right as it attempts to return a value.

What's going on here? A pastebin with my code can be found here: 
serverTest5.c --- http://pastebin.com/dHfVmKki
listQueue3.h  --- http://pastebin.com/gvpHFsdF

The array 'a' is defined and populated with the following code...

```
// Create Multidimensional Array for Processes
int a[clients][11];

// Create CommonFIFO
printf("\nSERVER: Making CommonFIFO...");
if ((mkfifo("CommonFIFO",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST)) {
    perror("\nERROR:  Can't create CommonFIFO.");
    exit(-1);
}

// Open CommonFIFO, reading
printf("\nSERVER: Opening CommonFIFO to read...");
if ((fda=open("CommonFIFO", O_RDONLY))<0)
    printf("\nERROR:  Can't open CommonFIFO to read."); 
// For each Client
for (i = 0; i < clients; i++) {
    // Read clientID, arrival time, and 5 bursts from CommonFIFO
    printf("\nSERVER: Servicing Client %d.\nSERVER: Reading CommonFIFO...", i+1);
    finish = read(fda, &input, sizeof input);
    printf("\nSERVER: Received job.");

    // Enter the data into the array
    a[i][0]  = input.clientID;
    a[i][1]  = 0;
    a[i][2]  = input.timeArrival;
    a[i][3]  = input.burst1;
    a[i][4]  = input.burst2;
    a[i][5]  = input.burst3;
    a[i][6]  = input.burst4;
    a[i][7]  = input.burst5;
    a[i][8]  = 0;
    a[i][9]  = 0;
    a[i][10] = 0;   
}
```

Comment: You probably have a buffer overrun in code previous to this. Show the definition and allocation of `a`.

Comment: It also seems you are sharing `i` as a global variable to perform all iterators, this is a bad practice and can bring conflicts if you have nested `for()` loops.

Comment: Matt, I've edited the topic post with the declaration and data population of the array 'a'. Hanevard, I realize that it's bad practice to reuse the same global variable i to perform all iterators. However, I'm not using nested for loops, although there are several non-nested for loops in the while loop.

Comment: You are undoubtedly corrupting the stack *somehow*, but we don't have enough information to tell how.  Try this: Run the program under `gdb`.  When it crashes, do `disas $pc $pc+1` and `info registers`.  Post the results.

Comment: (I tried to compile the code in your pastebin but it is incomplete, lacking `listQueue3.h` and perhaps also the associated `.c` file.  Another really useful thing for you to do at this point would be to remove code from that program until you have the *smallest possible*, *single-file*, *requiring only system headers* program that still crashes in the same fashion.)

Comment: Further observation: the function `incomplete` in isolation, modified only by giving it a local variable `i`, called from `main` with appropriate `a` and `clients` arguments, does not crash.

Comment: You do have nested loops all using the variable `i` because it is global. When you call the function `incomplete()`, it is using the same `i` as the `main()` program is trying to use. This wreaks havoc. Always make global variable names long enough to describe what they do (which means one letter is too short). Always use one-letter names for loop indexes (which means they can't be global because their name is too short). Whether you agree with name lengths or not, loop variables should be local to the function and preferably local to the loop (but sometimes you need the value after the loop).